# .gitignore fails to ignore all files except folders

Tags: git

Basically, I have the following folder structure:

```
repo 
     README.md
     testing_folder
           readingme.md
     resources_folder
```

And in my `.gitignore file`, I want to **ignore all files except folders in current directory** and this is what I have :

```
*
!.gitignore
!*/
```

When I do `git status`, this is what I get:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   .gitignore

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .gitignore
    modified:   README.md
```

**Problem is:** it doesn't show that the `testing_folder` and `resources_folder` are `untracked`. And when I try to do `git add testing/readingme.md`, I got the following error message:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
testing/readingme.md
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

I am starting to get really confused now because I have read so many other related posts. They seem to work but mine just doesn't work.

I tried including and excluding the `!*/` statement in .gitignore file but still the folders are not shown as `untracked`.

Comment: What about files in child directories? Do you want them ignored too, or only files in the top level directory?

Comment: An answer that cover both cases will be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recreated the directory structure you showed in the post, and when my `.gitignore` contains:

```
/*
!*/                                                                         
!.gitignore
```

I did notice that when the first line was `*` instead of `/*` I had the same problem as you. Adding the `/`, I would guess, gives git enough context to do what you want. With the `/*` my `git status` returns:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   .gitignore

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    testing_folder/
```

This will, essentially, only track files which aren't in the parent directory. The reason why `resources_folder` isn't showing up is because git doesn't track empty directories. [There are some ways to trick git into tracking empty folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/add-empty-directory-to-git-repository), but it's not default behavior.

Comment: I am getting a little bit confused now. So what is the major difference between `/*` and `*`  ? And when to use which ?

Comment: To be completely honest, I'm not really sure why `/*` works when `*` doesn't. I think generally if you use `*`, git will be VERY liberal in ignoring things, as you're telling it to just go ahead and ignore everything. Using `/*`, while seeming pretty similar, is explicitly not ignoring the root and that might let you be a bit more strict with what gets ignored and what is included.